# Create a Generic List Class in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am working on some university material and I Have the following question

Design and implement a collection class dedicated to storing all objects of company
documents as per the class hierarchy, inheriting from any .NET suitable collection class (e.g.
the ArrayList class, or generic List). The collection is to implement a single method
Page 2 of 5
GetDataOfAll() returning a string that concatenates data of all objects with suitable
separators. (The method will later be used to display data in a suitable output placeholder)

I wrote this:

```
class MainList : List<Document>
{
    public string GetDataFormAll()
    {
        string text = null;
        foreach (Document data in MainList)
        {
            text += data.GetData() + "\n";
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement this?

```
foreach (Document data in MainList)
```

This is giving me an error it is telling me that MainList is not of the correct type. How am I to implement this, please.

Comment: What about `foreach(Document data in this)`?

Comment: For each Something in my object. Not for each something in my type! Use `this`

Comment: Do not inherit from `List<>`, if you want to create a collection of user defined type then use `ICollection<>` or `BaseCollection` object to derive from. Alternatively you can derive from `IList<>`.

Comment: Correct? Yes. A lot more correct than leaving "Page 2 of 5" in the middle of copy-pasted text. (Actually: `(var dat  in this)` )

Comment: Stack overflow is not the best place for homework questions. Before trying to use this site, try to get a better grasp of the language. Your problem is not really about _what to do_, is one of being able to _read_ your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the `Document`s in your own (`this`) collection. Since a `List<T>` is `Enumerable<T>`, you can simply write a `foreach` loop over the `this`:

```
public string GetDataFormAll() {
    string text = null;
    foreach (Document data in this) {
        text += data.GetData() + "\n";
    }
    return text;
}
```

(Yes, I code like an *Egyptian*)

Answer (score 1):

Just another and shorter way, not necessarily better

```
public string GetDataFormAll()
{
    return string.Join("\n", this.Select(d => d.GetData());
}
```

And of course you can shorten it even more with `.Select(GetData)` syntax.

This will *not* add a `\n` after the last element. Depends on what you want.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `MainList` with `this`?

Comment: Yes, overlooked that.

Comment: Furthermore this is technically speaking not *fully* equivalent since the last new line is omitted here...

Comment: Yes, and as the text mentions 'separators' it might be a better solution.

Comment: I know, but perhaps it should be mentioned in the answer. (did +1, so no real issue)